# How to get focus on purticular div or success message after user submit a form

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4

I want to get focus on success message after the user submits a form or clicks on the submit button.
I tried alot but its not done yet.
I already created a form and the backend php code to upload into database and display success message but whenever I submit a form.
It's starting reloading and refreshing the page so i can't get focus on the success message. To see success message I have to scrolldown myself and see the message.

```
<form action="" role="form" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"  onsubmit="return validateContactForm()">
   <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text2" id="contact-name" placeholder="Your Name" required/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group form-group2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="10" pattern="\d{10}" title="Please enter exactly 10 digits" name="number2" id="contact-number" placeholder="Your Phone" required/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group form-group2">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email2" id="contact-email" placeholder="Your Email" required/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message2" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" id="submit"  name="submit2" onclick="$('#statusMessage')[0].focus()" class="btn south-btn">Send Message</button><br><br>
   <div id="statusMessage"> 
      <?php
            if (! empty($message2)) {
                       ?>
            <p id="success-message2" class='<?php echo $type; ?>Message2'><?php echo $message2; ?></p>
      <?php
              }
              ?>
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: The action of a form redirect you to the new page with the data as GET or POST. If you want to submit a form without redirecting, you can use: `<form onsubmit="myFunction()"></form>`

Comment: <form action="" role="form" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"  onsubmit="return validateContactForm()">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text2" id="contact-name" placeholder="Your Name" required/>
                            </div>

Comment: <div class="form-group form-group2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="10" pattern="\d{10}" title="Please enter exactly 10 digits" name="number2" id="contact-number" placeholder="Your Phone" required/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-group2">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email2" id="contact-email" placeholder="Your Email" required/>
                            </div>

Comment: <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="message2" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" id="submitbtn"   name="submit2"  class="btn south-btn">Send Message</button><br><br>

Comment: <div id="statusMessage"> 
                        <?php
                        if (! empty($message2)) {
                            ?>
                            <p id="success-message2" class='<?php echo $type; ?>Message2'><?php echo $message2; ?></p>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                        </form>

Comment: @Prashant Dave: You can edit your question after posting it

Answer (score 0):

You want to get focus on the success message once the form has been submitted:

```
<form action="" role="form" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"  onsubmit="return validateContactForm()">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="text2" id="contact-name" placeholder="Your Name" required/>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-group2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="10" pattern="\d{10}" title="Please enter exactly 10 digits" name="number2" id="contact-number" placeholder="Your Phone" required/>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-group2">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email2" id="contact-email" placeholder="Your Email" required/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="message2" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="submit"  name="submit2" onclick="$('#statusMessage')[0].focus()" class="btn south-btn">Send Message</button><br><br>
<div id="statusMessage"> 
    <?php if (!empty($message2)) { ?>
        <p id="success-message2" class='<?php echo $type; ?>Message2'><?php echo $message2; ?></p>
        <script>
         window.location.hash = '#success-message2';
        </script>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: this is working properly but displays #success_message in url ,which i dont want to display would please help me to fix it

Comment: Use this window.history.pushState("", "", '/yoururl'); after the script